# How to use Proxies in Doctrine 2

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, proxy, doctrine

I have the following configuration

```
 $isDevMode = \Config::get("DEBUG");
self::$config = Setup::createAnnotationMetadataConfiguration(array(APP_PATH.'models'), $isDevMode, APP_PATH.'proxies');

// naming strategy
$namingStrategy = new \DoctrineExtensions\CustomNamingStrategy();
self::$config->setNamingStrategy($namingStrategy);

// database configuration parameters
self::$conn = array(
    'url' => \Config::get('DB_DSN')
);

self::$evm = new \Doctrine\Common\EventManager;

// Table Prefix
$tablePrefix = new \DoctrineExtensions\TablePrefix(\Config::get('TABLE_PREFIX'));
self::$evm->addEventListener(Events::loadClassMetadata, $tablePrefix);
self::$entityManager = EntityManager::create(self::$conn, self::$config, self::$evm);
```

From Doctrine 2 Documentation which I understand, this should be generate Proxy classes in `APP_PATH.'proxies'` folder ( when `$isDevMode` is true. This should happen automatically).

Unfortunately it doesn't automatically generated classes. I don't know what the reason. However I generated these classes manually by using the following command `php vendor/bin/doctrine orm:generate-proxies`. Classes are generated and already exist in the folder. In order to try Proxy classes i wrote the following lines:

```
$qq = $this->repositoryPages
->createQueryBuilder('p')
->select('p.title')
->where('p.id = :id')
->setParameter('id', 6)
->getQuery()->getResult();
var_dump($qq);
```

Unfortunately for me this returns an associative array

```
array (size=1)
0 => 
   array (size=1)
     'title' => string 'Welcome' (length=7)
```

What is wrong and what I need to do to get the object ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to add one setter

```
self::config->setAutoGenerateProxyClasses(true);
```

I forgot to add example:

```
$this->repositoryPages
    ->createQueryBuilder('p')
    ->where('p.id = :id')
    ->setParameter('id', 6)
    ->getQuery()->getResult();
```

> [Query builder documentation](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/query-builder.html#working-with-querybuilder)

Comment: This is set from `createConfiguration` in Doctrine